# Is it possible to have 2 Error Logs per VirtualHost in Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, logging, httpd, errors

I have about 10 VirtualHosts and I like to keep the error_logs separated. Recently, I need to also have the error_logs all combined for some mod_security scanning.

If I define 2 ErrorLogs for a test VirtualDomain, I notice that no error's are being logged. Pretty strange.

Is it possible to have a CustomLog play the role of an ErrorLog?

Or am I defining my 2 ErrorLogs incorrectly?

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
    ServerName mydomain.net
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.net mydomain.net
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydomain
    ServerAdmin not@available.com
    UseCanonicalName Off

    ErrorLog logs/mydomain.net-error_log
    ErrorLog logs/unified_modsecurity-error_log

    CustomLog logs/mydomain.net-access_log combined
    UserDir disabled
    UserDir enabled mydomainuser
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it is not possible to have two ErrorLog directives per VirtualHost.  However, you could use Apache's ability to pipe to a command in order to log to two (or more) files using the UNIX 'tee' command:

> ErrorLog "|/usr/bin/tee -a /var/log/apache/error-1.log /var/log/apache/error-2.log"

Comment: I will try this. If I were to do `ErrorLog "|/usr/bin/tee -a /var/log/httpd/mydomain.net-error_log /var/log/httpd/unified_modsecurity-error_log"`, will the logs still roll over like how they do today?

Comment: *facepalm* logrotate should take care of the rotations. I'll give your solution a try, thanks!

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: I works also for access log. You can add combined at the end, after double quotes.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Apache 2.4 Logs documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html):

> By default the piped log process is spawned without invoking a shell. Use "|$" instead of "|" to spawn using a shell (usually with /bin/sh -c):
>
> This was the default behaviour for Apache 2.2.

Example:

```
# Write to files error-1.log and error-2.log, and echo to stdout
CustomLog "|$/usr/bin/tee -a /var/log/apache/error-1.log /var/log/apache/error-2.log"
```

Another issue I ran into:

- You should not have a space between the Double-Quote and Bar.

  - `"|$ ...` is valid.
  - `" |$ ...` is not.